# Exercise from book "Jumping Into C++"

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ by using the book "Jumping into C++" by Alex Allain 
and I have complications with one exercise.
Text for exercise goes:

> Design a program that finds all numbers from 1 to 1000 whose prime factors, when added
>   together, sum up to a prime number (for example, 12 has prime factors of 2, 2, and 3, which
>   sum to 7, which is prime). Implement the code for that algorithm.

I've written a code, which I thought it was good, but it's not working.

However, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    for (int number = 2 ; number < 1000 ; number++)
    {
            int sum = 0;
            int something = number;
            if (primeNumber(number) == true)
        {
            sum = number;
        }
        else
        {
            while (something != 1)
            {
                for (int factor = 2 ; factor <= number; factor++)
                {
                    if (primeNumber(factor) == true)
                    {
                        while(something % factor == 0)
                        {
                            something /= factor;
                            sum += factor;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (primeNumber(sum)== true)
        {
            cout << number << endl;
        }
    }
}
int primeNumber(int x)

{
    for (int i = 2 ; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, instead of just pasting your code here, and telling us that "it's not working", explain where you think the issue is. What does your code do? What does it not do?

Comment: Never use `if (primeNumber(sum)== true)`, use `if(primeNumber(sum))` instead.

Comment: Your `primeNumber()` doesn't work. if x<2, there is an undefined return value, and if x>=2 then return value is always `true` because 2 is prime.

Answer (score 0):

your primeNumber() function has something wrong - in the for loop, you shouldn't include the "else" statement. For instance, let x=9. Then when i starts with 2, we have (x%i==0) be false - thus according to your code, the function will immediately return "true" even though 9 is a composite number. The right code should be:

```
for (int i=2;i<x;i++)
if(x%i==0) return false;
return true;
```

In this way the code will examine all possible factors of x, and only when x is not an integer multiple of 2,3...or x-1 will the function return "true".

Hope this helps:)